# Increase the partition size of Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-8

I have 1TB hard disk.
I have installed ubuntu on a 30GB partition and the rest is for Windows 8.
I want to increase the ubuntu partition size to 100GB.
How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`, and maybe an image of Gparted partition map?  You can upload an image add the URL, and I'll add it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gparted for managing partitions.You can get it from software center.You can also use it in the live environment.
For complete instructions refer to the following link:
[partitioning using Gparted](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)